# Deliver unique file for each Salt minion

Tags: linux, saltstack

There is some directory path, like /etc/opt/mysoft which contents should be different for each minion.

So for minion A it contains config.ini with come contents and for minion B it contains config.ini with different contents and additionally file img.png.

What are my options? Can I copy files from /srv/salt/{minon-something-here}/ directory? Can I map some minion identifier to branch in svnfs, gitfs or hgfs?

Comment: are the files similar enough that you could template them?  How different are they between the hosts?

Comment: No, I cannot template them. Some are binary and some may be totally different.

Answer (score 0):

Use `- source: salt://mysoft/files/{{ grains['id'] }}` in any of the `file` states (e.g. `file.managed` or `file.recurse`), then put the host specific files in `/srv/salt/mysoft/files/{minion-id}/`. You can also use different grain, like `grains['fqdn']` and change the path appropriately.

Example:

```
/etc/opt/mysoft:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://mysoft/files/{{ grains['id'] }}
```

Files on master for minions with id `foo` and `bar`:

```
/srv/salt/mysoft/files/foo/config.ini
/srv/salt/mysoft/files/foo/img.png
/srv/salt/mysoft/files/bar/config.ini
/srv/salt/mysoft/files/bar/img.png
```